# Make backup (removal) logic in bash

Tags: bash, date, if-statement, backup, cut

I'm trying to apply a complex logic for removing old backups. Ideally, I'd like to only have backups up to 3 weeks (up to 3 weeklies, 7 dailies +-).

I'd like to rely on the filename for dating the file instead of actual creation date if possible.

This is how the example files look like:

```
Backup_2023-07-01.bak  Backup_2023-07-13.bak  Backup_2023-07-25.bak  Backup_2023-08-06.bak  Backup_2023-08-18.bak  Backup_2023-08-30.bak  Backup_2023-09-11.bak  Backup_2023-09-23.bak
Backup_2023-07-02.bak  Backup_2023-07-14.bak  Backup_2023-07-26.bak  Backup_2023-08-07.bak  Backup_2023-08-19.bak  Backup_2023-08-31.bak  Backup_2023-09-12.bak  Backup_2023-09-24.bak
Backup_2023-07-03.bak  Backup_2023-07-15.bak  Backup_2023-07-27.bak  Backup_2023-08-08.bak  Backup_2023-08-20.bak  Backup_2023-09-01.bak  Backup_2023-09-13.bak  Backup_2023-09-25.bak
Backup_2023-07-04.bak  Backup_2023-07-16.bak  Backup_2023-07-28.bak  Backup_2023-08-09.bak  Backup_2023-08-21.bak  Backup_2023-09-02.bak  Backup_2023-09-14.bak  Backup_2023-09-26.bak
Backup_2023-07-05.bak  Backup_2023-07-17.bak  Backup_2023-07-29.bak  Backup_2023-08-10.bak  Backup_2023-08-22.bak  Backup_2023-09-03.bak  Backup_2023-09-15.bak  Backup_2023-09-27.bak
Backup_2023-07-06.bak  Backup_2023-07-18.bak  Backup_2023-07-30.bak  Backup_2023-08-11.bak  Backup_2023-08-23.bak  Backup_2023-09-04.bak  Backup_2023-09-16.bak  Backup_2023-09-28.bak
Backup_2023-07-07.bak  Backup_2023-07-19.bak  Backup_2023-07-31.bak  Backup_2023-08-12.bak  Backup_2023-08-24.bak  Backup_2023-09-05.bak  Backup_2023-09-17.bak  Backup_2023-09-29.bak
Backup_2023-07-08.bak  Backup_2023-07-20.bak  Backup_2023-08-01.bak  Backup_2023-08-13.bak  Backup_2023-08-25.bak  Backup_2023-09-06.bak  Backup_2023-09-18.bak  Backup_2023-09-30.bak
Backup_2023-07-09.bak  Backup_2023-07-21.bak  Backup_2023-08-02.bak  Backup_2023-08-14.bak  Backup_2023-08-26.bak  Backup_2023-09-07.bak  Backup_2023-09-19.bak  Backup_2023-09-31.bak
Backup_2023-07-10.bak  Backup_2023-07-22.bak  Backup_2023-08-03.bak  Backup_2023-08-15.bak  Backup_2023-08-27.bak  Backup_2023-09-08.bak  Backup_2023-09-20.bak  Backup_KW1.bak
Backup_2023-07-11.bak  Backup_2023-07-23.bak  Backup_2023-08-04.bak  Backup_2023-08-16.bak  Backup_2023-08-28.bak  Backup_2023-09-09.bak  Backup_2023-09-21.bak
Backup_2023-07-12.bak  Backup_2023-07-24.bak  Backup_2023-08-05.bak  Backup_2023-08-17.bak  Backup_2023-08-29.bak  Backup_2023-09-10.bak  Backup_2023-09-22.bak
```

This is my script so far. The errors I get are not helping me understand, sadly.

```
#! /bin/bash
for filename in ./testfiles/*.bak; do
  thisfiledate=$("$filename" | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1)
  echo $thisfiledate
 #rename files made on sundays to weekly backups, dont delete them yet
if (date -d $thisfiledate +%u)=7;
  then mv $filename "Backup_KW" date -d thisfiledate +%U ".bak"
 #remove files older than one week
  elseif $thisfiledate<date +%F -d "-7 days" then rm #$filename
 #remove weekly files older than 3 weeks
  elseif $($filename | cud -d "KW" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1)<date -d "-3 weeks" +%U then rm #$filename
fi
done
```

The problem here is multi-faceted. I'm new to `cut`and `date`but otherwise have used bash in my backup scripts successfully. It's hard to find answers since there are a gazillion ways to do this.

I'm trying to reduce the amount of cans of worms to open just yet (such as regex, which I can't wrap my head around).

Please help! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please paste it into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix all errors it reports. The syntax you posted is not Bash, e.g. `if (date -d $thisfiledate +%u)=7;` and similar. At which point it makes little sense for others to look at it. (Is it perhaps a different type of shell? Then the question should be tagged accordingly, not `bash`.)

Comment: _The errors I get... _  You did not post any error message in your question.  Also, what is the `cud` doing in the last `elsif` line? Is it a typo and you meant `cut`?

Comment: As above, shellcheck, shellcheck, shellcheck AND the update your question with the corrected code. Here's one optimization for your though `thisfiledate=${filename#*_};thisfiledate=${thisfiledate%.*}`. Good luck.

Comment: One thing shellcheck won't really help you with is `if (date -d $thisfiledate +%u)=7`. you need something like `if [[ $(date -d $thisfiledate +%u)=7 ]] ; then echo OK ; else echo nope ; fi`. Use that as a guide to fix your other `if` statements and anywhere use you are relying `date`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running it in ShellCheck.net usually helps, but you need to know some syntax to read the suggestions...

```
Line 6:
if (date -d $thisfiledate +%u)=7;
^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this if expression. Fix to allow more checks.
                              ^-- SC1050 (error): Expected 'then'.
                              ^-- SC1072 (error): Expected 'then'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
                              ^-- SC1141 (error): Unexpected tokens after compound command. Bad redirection or missing ;/&&/||/|?
```

This isn't clear, and [the man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) doesn't help much.

Once you fix these, more errors will show; as pointed out above, I suspect you meant `cut` instead of `cud`. `cut` will complain about `-d "KW"` - it can't use multi-character delimiters. We can do better, though; we'll refactor while we're fixing the bugs.

## `if` Syntax

The basic structure of an `if` statement in `bash` is:

```
if LIST;
then LIST; 
[elif LISTA1; then LISTA2; [elif LISTN1; then LISTN2;] ] 
[else LISTX;] 
fi
```

**LIST** is a valid "command pipeline". `elif` and `else` are optional, and `elif` can be repeated.

Conditionals check return values, and zero means success, while any nonzero is failure. ALWAYS keep that in mind.

Your command -

```
if (date -d $thisfiledate +%u)=7; then ...
```

The `(` opens a *subshell*, running the commands inside in a forked environment. I'm pretty sure this is *not* what you meant.
The `=` makes no sense in this context. Its left-hand side is not an assignable token, it isn't inside a *comparison construct*,and it isn't a redirection like `<` or `>` or a pipe (`|`), or a conditional operator like `&&` or `||`, or whitespace, or a semicolon... it's none of the things that it can figure out, so the parser bails and tells you that you did it wrong.

All of this is because what you *meant* to do, a conditional comparison, requires a different syntax. There are a few.

#### Exit Codes

When you run any command LIST it returns a status to the shell, and that's what is checked in the `if`.

```
$: date -d 2023-10-10 +%u
2

$: echo $?
0

$: if date -d 2023-10-10 +%u # The `2` output IS NOT TESTED HERE.
then echo ok; else echo no; fi
2
ok
```

If you want a test on the output you have to construct your test correctly. There are several ways to accomplish this; let's capture that data separately to make the point.

```
$: weekday=$(date -d 2023-10-10 +%u)

$: echo $weekday
2
```

The success of the `date` command isn't explicitly checked here, but if it fails there will be nothing in `weekday`, so that's often considered good enough. Be prepared.

```
$: weekday=$(date -d 'foo bar baz' +%u)
date: invalid date ‘foo bar baz’

$: echo $weekday
```

You used this `$(cmd)` construct in your code, though yours is broken:

```
$: thisfiledate=$("$filename" | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1)
bash: Backup_KW1.bak: command not found
```

(You meant to work with the value in the variable as a string, but executed it as a command. You needed something like `echo "$filename"` - we'll come back to that.)

#### special structures for testing conditions with if CMD

Testing the output is a separate step. You were trying to use a math-equal comparison, so let's do that. Here's one way -

```
$: weekday=$(date -d 2023-10-15 +%u)

$: if (( 7 == weekday )); then echo got seven; else echo nope; fi
got seven
```

Some things to note here:
***double parens*** create an *arithmetic testing* scope, while single parens create a subshell. A subshell might be what's intended sometimes, but isn't what you wanted here.

```
$: if (7==weekday); then echo got seven; else echo nope; fi
bash: 7==weekday: command not found
nope

$: if (echo foo); then echo success; else echo nope; fi
foo
success

$: if echo foo; then echo success; else echo nope; fi
foo
success
```

The `if` accepts the single parens, executes the command in a subshell, and tests the *exit code* from the subshell. You usually don't need the subshell parens at all; you'd only want them in certain situations, which are out of scope here.

Using DOUBLE parens is a different thing entirely, which does an *arithmetic evaluation* on what's inside. `(( 7 == weekday ))` reads the seven, takes the `==` to means it is to check for arithmetic equality, reads the value in `weekday`, compares as directed and returns an exit code of zero if the test was *true*, and one (any nonzero is considered failure) if the test was *false*.

Note also that I was able to leave the `$` dollar sign off the `weekday` variable *in that arithmetic context*, though it works fine (if a subtle bit differently) if you leave it on.

So one version of your test might be:

```
weekday=$(date -d $thisfiledate +%u)
if (( weekday == 7 )); then mv "$old" "$new"; fi
```

There are several other ways you could have structured this test.

You could have done it as a string comparison, as long as you are clear that is what you are doing.

```
$: if [[ 7 == $weekday ]]; then echo got seven; else echo nope; fi
got seven
```

#### Caveats

Note that in this construct, spaces are *required* in the square brackets. This is true whether using `bash` double brackets or [`test`](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html) single brackets. Both `[[` and `[` allow either double `==` or single `=` as equivalent; single-equal is more portable, but can lead to hard-to-debug accidental assignments... you can make those less likely by putting any literals on the left hand side.

```
$: [[ 7 == $weekday ]] && echo got seven
got seven

$: [[ 7=$weekday ]] && echo got seven
got seven

$: [ 7==$weekday ] && echo got seven
got seven

$: [ 7=$weekday ] && echo got seven
got seven

$: [[7==$weekday ]] && echo got seven
bash: [[7==7: command not found

$: [[ 7==$weekday]] && echo got seven
bash: conditional binary operator expected

$: [7==$weekday ] && echo got seven
bash: [7==7: command not found

$: [ 7=$weekday] && echo got seven
bash: [: missing `]'
```

ALWAYS watch for accidental assignment errors any time you see single-equals used in a test, though string comparisons with `[[` or `[` are generally safe.

```
$: foo=1; bar=foo; [[ $bar=2 ]] && echo true || echo nope # oh, no...
true

$: echo "bar='$bar' foo='$foo'" # corrupted data
bar='foo' foo='1'
```

Be careful with the arithmetic syntax tho...

```
$: (( 7==weekday )) && echo true
true

$: (( 7=weekday )) && echo true
bash: ((: 7=weekday : attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "=weekday ")

$: (( weekday=5 )) && echo true # oops! overwritten value, ALWAYS true
true

$: (( $weekday=5 )) && echo true # don't trust $ to prevents this -
bash: ((: 5=5 : attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "=5 ")

$: foo=1; bar=foo; (( $bar=2 )) && echo true; # OOPS!!
true

$: echo "bar='$bar' foo='$foo'" # wrong answer AND corrupted data
bar='foo' foo='2'
```

By the time you realize it is broken, it will have been happily using wrong data in the wrong logic block for weeks...

#### Brevity

You can use `$(cmd)` *in place* in your test -

```
if [[ 7 == $(date -d $thisfiledate +%u) ]]; then ... # compared as string
```

or

```
if (( 7 == $(date -d $thisfiledate +%u) )); then ... # compared as integers
```

#### `elif`

`elseif` is not valid. See above - use `elif`.

```
$: if false; then echo false; elif true; then echo true; else echo nope; fi
true

$: if false; then echo false; elseif true; then echo true; else echo nope; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

Note that while the error message is confusing, the only change was the `elif` to `elseif`, and it broke. What's actually happening is that it doesn't recognize `elseif` as a keyword, so treats it as a command token - it might be the name of a script you wrote, for example. That means the `then` behind it (which *is* a keyword) shouldn't be there.

As one more option, you can use a [`case`](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-case-relational-operators) statement.

```
case $(date -d $thisfiledate +%u) in 7) mv "$old" "$new";; esac
```

## Other Errors

#### CMD is parsed before execution

Look at that `mv` statement. Your original code:

```
  then mv $filename "Backup_KW" date -d thisfiledate +%U ".bak"
```

c.f. the [`mv` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1p.html)
Aside from the dash-parameters, `mv` either expects *exactly two files* as arguments, or the last argument must be a directory into which the other arguments will be copied.

That means if it had gotten far enough to execute, your command above would have immediately failed because there is no `-d` argument to `mv`; aside from that, what you told it was to look for a directory named `.bak` into which it should copy files named `Backup_KW`, `date`, `thisfiledate`, and `+%U`, none of which would it find.

What you wanted:

```
  then mv "$filename" Backup_KW$(date -d $thisfiledate +%U).bak
```

This executes `$(date -d $thisfiledate +%U)` and **replaces** it *as the line is being parsed* with the output, which is done before passing the names to `mv`. What `mv` sees when that's done is, for example,

```
 mv Backup_2023-10-15.bak BackupKW42.bak
```

#### Logic and testing

The initial `if` test will be `false` when the `date` *fails* on all the existing weekly backup files and outputs nothing. Those aren't a problem here, but the error message is ugly and unnecessary with a little restructuring.

Those files will then fall through to the next test -

```
 #remove files older than one week
  elseif $thisfiledate<date +%F -d "-7 days" then rm #$filename
```

Since you have ordered the fields YEAR-MONTH-DAY and are apparently always using leading zeros in two-digit month and day, you *can* test these as string comparisons:

```
 #remove files older than one week
  elif [[ $thisfiledate < $(date +%F -d "-7 days") ]]; then rm "$filename"
```

But if a file ever misses a leading zero it's likely to break.

```
$: [[ 2023-9-9 > 2023-10-10 ]] && echo a is after b || echo a is before b # oops
a is after b
```

`date`'s `%s` returns the UNIX epoch, a simple integer that can be cleanly compared.

Also, Daily and Weekly files are different filename patterns, so it's easy to factor them out and process them differently as you go.

## My rewrite

```
#! /bin/bash -x
oneweekago=$(    date -d '-7 days'  +%s ) # not checking time of day
threeweeksago=$( date -d '-21 days' +%s ) # not checking day of week
oldestkeep=$(    date -d '-3 weeks' +%U ) # for renamed weeklies
cd "${target_directory:=/tmp/testfiles/}" || { echo >&2 "unable to change to '${target_directory}'"; exit 1; }
for filename in Backup_*.bak; do # changed working directory simplifies filename handling
  mark=${filename//[^0-9-]/}     # remove all characters not digits or dashes (assumes ASCII or UTF-8)
  case $mark in
  # daily files have dashes
  *-*) filedate=$( date -d $mark +%s )
       if (( filedate < threeweeksago ));    then rm "$filename"
       elif (( 7 == $(date -d $mark +%u) )); then mv "$filename" Backup_KW$(date -d $mark +%U).bak
       elif (( filedate < oneweekago ));     then rm "$filename"
       fi
       ;;
  # weekly backups only have the week number, e.g., Backup_KW42.bak
    *) (( mark < oldestkeep )) && rm "$filename"
       ;;
  esac
done
```

I set `-x` so there would be behavior-traceable output.
(You might want to add some logging...)

I created a `./testfiles/` directory and included all your example files, but those are all older than three weeks so I created (empty) daily files for all the days since September, and ran it.

For comparison reference:

```
++ date -d '-7 days' +%s
+ oneweekago=1699904288
++ date -d '-21 days' +%s
+ threeweeksago=1698694688
++ date -d '-3 weeks' +%U
+ oldestkeep=44
+ cd /tmp/testfiles/
```

Then as it ran through all the files up to the end of October:

```
+ for filename in Backup_*.bak
+ mark=2023-10-30
+ case $mark in
++ date -d 2023-10-30 +%s
+ filedate=1698642000
+ ((  filedate < threeweeksago  ))
+ rm Backup_2023-10-30.bak
```

It deleted them as being more than three weeks old.

When it got to Halloween:

```
+ for filename in Backup_*.bak
+ mark=2023-10-31
+ case $mark in
++ date -d 2023-10-31 +%s
+ filedate=1698728400
+ ((  filedate < threeweeksago  ))
++ date -d 2023-10-31 +%u
+ ((  7 == 2  ))
+ ((  filedate < oneweekago  ))
+ rm Backup_2023-10-31.bak
```

It was *not* more than three weeks old, but it also wasn't a Sunday, and it *WAS* more than one week old, so it got deleted too, as did the next ones up to November 5th:

```
+ for filename in Backup_*.bak
+ mark=2023-11-05
+ case $mark in
++ date -d 2023-11-05 +%s
+ filedate=1699160400
+ ((  filedate < threeweeksago  ))
++ date -d 2023-11-05 +%u
+ ((  7 == 7  ))
++ date -d 2023-11-05 +%U
+ mv Backup_2023-11-05.bak Backup_KW45.bak
```

Which was a Sunday, so it was copied as the week 45 backup.
Subsequent days were again deleted until Sunday the 12th, kept as week 46.

As of the 14th it stopped deleting files.

```
+ for filename in Backup_*.bak
+ mark=2023-11-14
+ case $mark in
++ date -d 2023-11-14 +%s
+ filedate=1699941600
+ ((  filedate < threeweeksago  ))
++ date -d 2023-11-14 +%u
+ ((  7 == 2  ))
+ ((  filedate < oneweekago  ))
```

It silently left them alone up to Sunday the 19th which it moved/saved as week 47.

When it hit `Backup_KW1.bak` it removed it as out of date.

```
+ case $mark in
+ ((  mark < oldestkeep  ))
+ rm Backup_KW1.bak
```

If I run it again, there's nothing left to delete or rename, so it just audits and ignores them all, leaving these:

```
$: ls -l testfiles
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 20 14:16 Backup_2023-11-14.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 20 14:16 Backup_2023-11-15.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 20 14:16 Backup_2023-11-16.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 20 14:16 Backup_2023-11-17.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 20 14:16 Backup_2023-11-18.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 20 14:16 Backup_2023-11-20.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 20 14:16 Backup_KW45.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 20 14:16 Backup_KW46.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Nov 20 14:16 Backup_KW47.bak
```